# UICollectionView underneath the navigation bar when shown as a page in a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios7, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I have an iOS 7 app that has a UIPageViewController. Each page it displays has a UICollectionView that takes up the entire page except for the navigation bar. iOS 7 normally adjusts collection view edge insets so it is positioned below the navigation bar and goes underneath it as you scroll it up.

But when my collection view is displayed in the UIPageViewController, it's edge insets are not being  adjusted because the nav bar is owned by the page view controller, not the page the collection view is on. I have tried to set the edge insets on the collection view, but then it pushes the bottom of the collection view off the screen.

Does anyone know how you are supposed to setup an collection view inside of a page view controller in iOS 7?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and out of frustration i ended up doing this:

In the UIPageViewController i added:

```
[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeAll];
```

and in the Collection View `viewDidLoad`:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)]) {
    UIEdgeInsets currentInsets = self.collectionView.contentInset;
    self.collectionView.contentInset = (UIEdgeInsets){
        .top =64,
        .bottom = currentInsets.bottom,
        .left = currentInsets.left,
        .right = currentInsets.right
    };
}
```

In the storyboard i disabled the all the "Extended Edge" and the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" for both views.
Not exactly an elegant solution but it works.